# Added drives to raid array, and changed it from 5 to 6 but it looks like I forgot to add a filesystem to them

Tags: raid, mdadm

```
mdadm --detail output

Version : 1.2 Creation Time : Tue Jul 21 15:52:43 2020 Raid Level : raid6 Array Size : 29298912768 (27941.62 GiB 30002.09 GB) Used Dev Size : 9766304256 (9313.87 GiB 10000.70 GB) Raid Devices : 5 Total Devices : 5 Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Intent Bitmap : Internal

Update Time : Thu Sep  1 06:03:27 2022
      State : clean
Active Devices : 5 Working Devices : 5 Failed Devices : 0 Spare Devices : 0

     Layout : left-symmetric
 Chunk Size : 512K

       Name : peterspc:127
       UUID : 33ddab84:a3066cc3:88d7ea2a:adc72083
     Events : 103455

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
   0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
   1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
   3       8       33        2      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   5       8       96        3      active sync   /dev/sdg
   4       8       64        4      active sync   /dev/sde
```

The array size and used dev size are smaller than they should be as each drive is 10 TB.

sdg and sde aren't sdg1 and sde1... So I think I screwed up.

How do I get the correct space across them?

Comment: Do you see the correct size (with new drives) of array?

Comment: The sizes look correct. You are using RAID6, so you only get 3 drives worth of space, which would be 30 TB in your case.

Comment: I thought Array size referd to the entire array, then Used Dev Size referred to the amount used for parity. Which would be correct for the original 3 drives, but not for 5. It should be Array size of 50 TB and Used Dev of 20. Plus, df -h reports a size of 19 TB. DO I just need to remount?

Comment: @average650, you should extend the filesystem to see from terminal these 30TB

Comment: @RomeoNinov   okay that makes sense. Probably should have thought of that!